Preempt a dag run
I have a DAG that does some data processing tasks and runs on a daily schedule. I now have the requirement that the DAG run in an "on-demand" way, triggered by a user or some other event. There is also a possibility that a user might want to retrigger the DAG after it has already started running (imagine: someone realises they forgot to upload a newer version of an input file and wants the process to restart, rather than wait for it to complete on old data).
The on-demand feature is managed by a new DAG that will trigger the original DAG with a TriggerDagRunOperator. The problem is I'm not sure how to preempt the data processing DAG from the new DAG. Is this even possible in Airflow?
A simple code example:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from time import sleep
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    'retries': 0,
    'depends_on_past': False,
}

with DAG('dag1', schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args, tags=['TEST']) as dag1:
    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    trigger_dag2 = TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id='trigger_dag2',
                                         trigger_dag_id='dag2',
                                         wait_for_completion=False,
                                         reset_dag_run=True)
    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    start >> trigger_dag2 >> end

with DAG('dag2', schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args, tags=['TEST'], max_active_runs=1) as dag2:
    wait_task = PythonOperator(task_id='wait_task', python_callable=lambda: sleep(120))
    some_step = DummyOperator(task_id='some_step')
    wait_task2 = PythonOperator(task_id='wait_task_2', python_callable=lambda: sleep(120))


    wait_task >> some_step >> wait_task2

Here, dag1 is the new manager DAG and dag2 is the data processor.
When I run dag1, it triggers dag2 properly and then immediately completes. When I trigger dag1 again, it triggers dag2 but the second dag run for dag2 is in a queued state, and the first dag run is still going. In this situation, I want to terminate the first dag run and have the second dag run begin immediately. Does airflow have any way to let a dag run preempt a previous dag run?

It seems this is possible with a custom Python operator that can find the targeted dag run and set its state and the states of its task instances to FAILED.
This seems to do what I want:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from time import sleep
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.models import DagRun
from airflow.utils.state import DagRunState

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    'retries': 0,
    'depends_on_past': False,
}

def kill_dag2(**context):
    dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id='dag2', state='running',)

    if (dag_runs):
        for dag_run in dag_runs:
            print("Prior dag run found: " + dag_run.run_id)
            dag_run.set_state(DagRunState.FAILED)
            for task_instance in dag_run.get_task_instances():
                if (task_instance.state == DagRunState.RUNNING):
                    print("Setting task instance to failed for task_id: " + task_instance.task_id)
                    task_instance.set_state(DagRunState.FAILED)
    else:
        print("No prior dag run found")
        

with DAG('dag1', schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args, tags=['TEST']) as dag1:
    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    
    kill_prior_dag = PythonOperator(task_id='kill_prior_dag',
                                    python_callable=kill_dag2)
    
    trigger_dag2 = TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id='trigger_dag2',
                                         trigger_dag_id='dag2',
                                         wait_for_completion=False,
                                         reset_dag_run=True,
                                         poke_interval=10)
    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    start >> kill_prior_dag >> trigger_dag2 >> end

with DAG('dag2', schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args, tags=['TEST'], max_active_runs=1) as dag2:
    wait_task = PythonOperator(task_id='wait_task', python_callable=lambda: sleep(120))
    some_step = DummyOperator(task_id='some_step')
    wait_task2 = PythonOperator(task_id='wait_task_2', python_callable=lambda: sleep(120))


    wait_task >> some_step >> wait_task2

